# Flutter bottom sheet

Tags: flutter

How can I build that without resorting to packages?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ListWheelScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html). Also there is a [`CupertinoPicker`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html) can be customize to archive this.

```dart
 ListWheelScrollView(
  itemExtent: 40,
  magnification: .4,
  children:
```